# SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'too many SQL variables'

Tags: servicestack

When using `db.SaveAll(collection)` and a Sqlite database it seems to trigger the below error if the collection is too large:

> SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'too many SQL variables'.

The collections are not that big, maybe a couple of thousand entries at most.  Is this a Sqlite limit?  Can I configure this?

I have done workaround of inserting items one by one (works extremely slow), would just like to know for future reference if this is intended behaviour or I am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Edit: seems the insert limit for sqlite is 500.  I am guessing I have to batch this myself

Answer (score 3):

The answer was to do inside a transaction.  It changed it from 10mins to insert 10,000 records to 7 seconds.

```
using (var dbLite = _sqlLiteFactory.Open())
{
    using (IDbTransaction trans = dbLite.OpenTransaction())
    {
        collection.Each(x => dbLite.Save(x));

        trans.Commit();
    }
}
```